# "Fight Academy" or "Fighting Academy?"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

What's more accurate, "Fight Academy" or "Fighting Academy" or is it equally correct to use either one.

I have seen both being used and when I compare it to "Fight Club," it seems that "Fight Academy" is also correct. However, "Fighting Academy" seems more intuitive, but I don't know exactly why.

P.S. I'm a non-native English speaker.

Comment: In the UK it would probably specify the type of fighting. "Boxing Academy" sounds right. In general, a "Martial Arts Academy" might cover that and other forms.

Comment: We're trying to choose the correct one between the two as it will be the name of the academy and I can't figure out which is more accurate.

Comment: Fighting academy sounds like the academy is fighting - I would go with Fight Academy to get some rep off Fight Club

Comment: As Andrew said, it's a Boxing Academy and it doesn't sound like the academy is boxing. Still can't figure out the proper terminology.

Answer (score 3):

Neither of those terms is common - having seemingly never come across them in my life until now. Google give about 227k results for "fight academy" as in "Deadeye Dick's Fight Academy" and 102k for the other.

That said, I can't discern any particular rule that would seem to govern except that the examples above all point to the use of a noun, rather than a verb -- music academy, science academy -- so that boxing (and thus fighting) work because they are gerunds, not adjectives in this context.

So: "fighting academy."

Aside: are you teaching "fighting" or something else? Perhaps that other thing should be in the name instead, as both more descriptive and less confusing!